# List all values $ p, q, r$ for which the statement $(p\to q) \to(q \lor r)$ is False

Tags: discrete-mathematics

List all values $p$, $q$, $r$ for which the statement $(p\to q) \to(q \lor r)$ is False

Confused about this. I created a truth table and don't understand the question.

Comment: Which rows of the truth table result in the statement being false.

Answer (score 3):

The only way for an implication $A\rightarrow B$ to be false is for $A$ to be true and $B$ to be false. So you must have $p\rightarrow q$ true and $q\vee r$ false. The only way fror $q\vee r$ to be false is for both $q$ and $r$ to be false.
Ok    so $q$ and $r$ are false what about $p$ ? $p\rightarrow q $ is true, and $q$ is false so $p$ must also be false. Thus the only way is for $p,q,r$ all to be false.

Answer (score 0):

When is $(p\to q)\to(q\vee r)$ false?

An implication is false when the antecedant is true yet the consequent false.

$$(p\to q)\wedge\neg(q\vee r) \\ (\neg p\vee q)\wedge(\neg q \wedge\neg r)\\ \neg p\wedge\neg q\land \neg r$$

This implication is false when $p,q,r$ are all false.$$\begin{array}{lll}p & q & r\\ F & F & F \end{array}$$